# What would it take to add support for the Contacts API to google-api-ruby-client?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'd like to use the [official Ruby client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/) to access the Contacts API, but that one is not on the [list of supported APIs](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/SupportedAPIs). What would it take to change that? I'm willing to pitch in, but a shove in the right direction would help. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that the reason has to do with a lack of discoverability features in the Contacts API. It seems that google-api-ruby-client only supports discoverable APIs for now.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this already supported with the [Google Data on Rails](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html) API? Integrating this in the official Ruby client library shouldn't be that much work.

Comment: Possibly, but that library doesn't support OAuth. Even if that feature was added to the library, I'd prefer to use instead what has been referred to in several places as the officially supported library. May be a reasonable plan B though.